# Cómo eliminar el residuo de la imagen anterior usando ViewPager (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-imageview, android-viewpager

Estoy intentando hacer un slide de fotografías con ViewPager, algo que siempre fue muy "fácil" de implementar utilizando texto o fragments, pero estoy en el siguiente dilema.
Al pasar de una página a otra, debajo de la la imagen actual aparecen "residuos" o partes de la imagen anterior. No estoy usando Fragments en este caso.
Básicamente, como la imagen que adjunto.
[enter link description here](http://www.mediafire.com/view/v079v8lzz8jngry/Screenshot_2020-01-14-20-38-36-144_pmcoder.com.savewhatsappstatus.jpg)

Cosas que he intentado y no solucionaron el problema:
Cambié de ViewPager a ViewPager2, dejé de utilizar PhotoView de Chrisbanes y escribí mi propia implementación, cambiar el Background del ViewPager por cada vez que cambio de página.

El código es el siguiente:

```
    public class ImageGalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageGalleryAdapter.PageViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<String> media;
    private Map<String, String> tags;
    private GalleryActivity galleryActivity;

    public ImageGalleryAdapter(ArrayList<String> media, Activity activity) {
        this.media = media;
        tags = new HashMap<>();
        galleryActivity = (GalleryActivity) activity;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PageViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new PageViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.images_gallery, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PageViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final String imagePath = media.get(position);
        tags.put(String.valueOf(position), imagePath);

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 2;
        String tag = tags.get(String.valueOf(position));
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(tag, options);

       holder.bind(bitmap, position);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (media != null)
            return media.size();
        else
            return 0;
    }

    class PageViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        PhotoView photoView;

        PageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            photoView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.photo);
        }

        void bind(Bitmap bitmap, int position) {

            photoView.setImageResource(0);

            photoView.setTag(String.valueOf(position));
            photoView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            photoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            galleryActivity.setMediaMap(tags);
        }
    }
}
```

El Layout es:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<example.gallery.mainActivity.model.FrameLayoutExtends
    android:id="@+id/videoGalleryLayout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
        android:id="@+id/photo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/playIconVideo"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_media_play"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:visibility="gone"
        tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

</example.gallery.mainActivity.model.FrameLayoutExtends>
```

Cualquier idea es bienvenida.
Gracias

Comment: Recientemente intenté usando photoView.setImageResource(0);

y con
photoView.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent); pero tampoco ha funcionado.